# Authorization against Azure Storage Emulator using postman?

Tags: azure, rest, http-headers, postman, azure-storage-emulator

I am trying to authenticate using the Azure Storage emulator's fixed account/key used for the Azure storage emulator Shared Key authentication.

When sending an anonymous request I get the correct response

[image: anonymousRequest]

but when adding Authorization Header I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
   <code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo</code>
   <message xml:lang="en-US">Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.
RequestId:6d2cc79e-6bce-451c-a6f0-f10e0876f640
Time:2019-07-29T19:22:48.6402756Z</message>
</error>.
```

This is the key-value pair for the Authorization header: 
[image: auth-header]

Any idea on how to resolve this? I have followed documentation but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you're using a `Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL`, you don't need to add `Authorization` header as authorization information is already included in your `SAS URL` (`sig` part of your URL).

One thing that you may want to do is change the value of `Accept` header and set its value to `application/json;odata=fullmetadata`.

Authorization header comes into picture when you don't use SAS. I noted that you're simply passing your account key as part of your authorization header. That won't work. You will actually need to compute the authorization header. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key.